# Validate that a file is a picture in PHP

Tags: php, image, security, validation

If a file is uploaded to the server, is there a way using PHP, to make sure that it's actually a picture and not just a file with a .jpg or .gif extension?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using (part) of the GD library.

[PHP: GD - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)

```
array getimagesize ( string $filename [, array &$imageinfo ] )
```

The first element of the array will be 0 if there is no image. [PHP: getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

If you don't have GD installed (most of the time you will), you can read the file header as [Shane mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581136/in-php-how-can-i-validate-that-a-file-is-a-picture/1581164#1581164).

EDIT:
Actually, as Neal pointed out in the comments, **the GD library is not even required to use this function.** So use it.

Comment: @Neal - Actually, I didn't! I had no idea. Thanks for pointing that out. Answer has been edited. Not the first time I've been RTFM'd

Comment: No problem ^_^ Happy to help!

Comment: It is better and *faster* to use `exif_imagetype`.

Comment: Official docs say "Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image"

Comment: this function run too slowly. do you have any better idea ?

Comment: like @ymakux said, official docs say to NOT USE getimagesize, see https://techlister.com/php/check-if-the-uploaded-file-is-an-image-in-php/ that guy proved it

Answer (score 4):

Header check is not enough for checking the validity of an image file.
PHP Documentation clearly expresses that you shouldn't use `getimagesize` to check that a  given file is a valid image. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

I use the following function to validate a image file:

```php
    /**
     * Returns TRUE if $path is a valid Image File
     *
     * @param string $path
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function isImage(string $path)
    {

        if (!is_readable($path)) {
            return false;
        }

        // see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php for Constants
        // adjust this array to your needs
        $supported = [IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG, IMAGETYPE_PNG];

        $type = exif_imagetype($path);

        // $type can be valid, but not "supported"
        if (!in_array($type, $supported)) {
            return false;
        }

        // check the image content, header check is not enough
        $image = false;
        switch ($type) {
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $image = @imagecreatefromgif($path);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $image = @imagecreatefrompng($path);
                break;
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $image = @imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
                break;
        }
        return (!!$image);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way would be to look at the beginning bytes of the file and test for 'magic number' file specifier. [Here is a list of magic numbers](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html).

Comment: That would be the more efficient than firing up GD, but I think with the binary opens, etc.. is a bit over the head of most people.

Comment: If that's true - its pretty disappointing. Don't most of the people here have CS degrees?

Comment: I don't.. but I've been writing code since I was 7. Surprisingly, many people can get degrees without actually knowing what they're supposed to. I speak from experience, because I do actually have a degree in civil engineering, and I knew a lot of "sliders" that just slid by. A degree doesn't mean anything. Proof that you can do something does.

Comment: Oh and I believe that a large number of the users of this site do not have CS degrees. Most people end up here from Google who are trying to learn something about the language they are learning.

Comment: Agreed - I saw that for myself. However - it is still disappointing to think of people with programming jobs (as I assume many of these do) and that binary opens are over their head.

Comment: This works but I'm not sure if it will catch a corrupt image. It should probably be complemented by another check.

Answer (score 3):

best way to check if file is an image

```
function is_image($path)
{
    $a = getimagesize($path);
    $image_type = $a[2];

    if(in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_GIF , IMAGETYPE_JPEG ,IMAGETYPE_PNG , IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

more: http://www.binarytides.com/php-check-if-file-is-an-image/

Comment: [Caution:](http://php.net/manual/function.getimagesize.php) **Do not use** `getimagesize()` to check that a given file is a valid image.

Answer (score 2):

**For the record: Now in 2013+ we can:**

For max. compatibility (If you don't have GD library).
Use the always available [mime-content-type](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) ((PHP 4 >= 4.3.0, PHP 5))

```
$type = mime_content_type($filename);
if (strstr($type, 'image/'))
{
    echo 'is image';
}
```

Comment: still available for php 7