# How to verify whether the file is the picture in PHP?

Tags: php, image

How to verify whether the file (jpg, png, gif) is the picture in PHP?

I need function like this:

```
boolean isImage($url);
```

Or:

```
boolean isImage(binary_data_from_http_post);
```

I think second way is better, because works before saving file on disk.

I don't want to experiment with copying from random page found in google.

Comment: When you googled your question - what did you find?

Comment: Are you speaking of checking the MIME type, checking the extension? Checking if GD can create an image? Please be more specific - perhaps also specify what you need that information for, it may help give perspective.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate that a file is a picture in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581136/validate-that-a-file-is-a-picture-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use finfo

http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Or get image size

http://de.php.net/getimagesize

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's GD extension to check for a valid image:

```
function isImage($url) {
    $buffer = file_get_contents($url);
    $img = imagecreatefromstring($buffer);
    return ($img !== false) ? true : false;
}
```

If you already have the potential image data you can use this instead:

```
function isImage($data) {
    return (imagecreatefromstring($data) !== false) ? true : false;
}
```