# Best practice database transactions and storing files onto filesystem in PHP

Tags: php, transactions, pdo

What would be the best practice regarding integrity if a user uploads user data together with a file where the user data is stored in a database and the file is stored onto the filesystem?

At the moment I would do something like the following code snippet using PHP and PDO (code is not tested, but I hope you will got my point). I don't like the save image part in the User::insert method. Is there a good way around this?

```
<?php
User::insert($name, $image, $ext);

Class User{
    static public function insert($name, $image, $ext){
        $conn = DB_config::get();

        $conn->beginTransaction();

        $sth = $conn->prepare("
                                INSERT INTO users (name)
                                values(:name)
                                ;");

        $sth->execute(array(
                                ":name"     =>  $name
                                ));

        if ($conn->lastInsertId() > -1 && Image::saveImage($image, IMAGE_PATH . $conn->lastInsertId(). $ext))
            $conn->commit();
        else
            $conn->rollback();

        return $conn->lastInsertId();
    }
}

Class Image{
    static public function saveimage($image, $filename){
        $ext = self::getExtensionFromFilename($filename);

        switch($ext){
            case "jpg":
            case "jpeg":
                return imagejpeg(imagecreatefromstring($image), $filename);
        }

        return false;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by integrity. If you mean validating if a file is an uncorrupt image you could have an ImageValidator class with checks as described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581136/validate-that-a-file-is-a-picture-in-php

Comment: Also, you might be interested in the DAO pattern: http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/php/guide.php

Comment: @JamesPoulson with integrity I mean if for whatever reason the user couldn't be stored in the database, the image must not be stored and vice versa. But maybe I formulated my question wrong, but I was indeed looking for some kind of design pattern to separate the User and Image stuff. Your links are very helpful. Thanks

Comment: @cookie I'd do something similar to what's been suggested below: check image in code, save image perhaps using uniqid (technically unique) or md5 hash (file integrity, relatively unique), register image in dedicated table (decouples and allows N images), register user, if user registration is cancelled or user is deleted remove image in db and on disk, if user registration successful update image table with PK/id of user.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this.

- Save the image to the disk in a work area. It's best to save it to
  the work area that's on the same volume as the eventual destination.
  It's also best to put it in a separate directory.
- Start the transaction with the database.
- Insert your user.
- Rename the image file after the User ID.
- Commit the transaction.

What this does is it performs the riskiest operation first, the saving of the image. All sorts of things can happen here -- system can fail, disk can fill up, connection can close. This is (likely) the most time consuming of your operations, so it's definitely the riskiest.

Once this is done, you start the transaction and insert the user.

If the system fails at this time, your insert will be rolled back, and the image will be in the temporary directory. But for your real system, effectively "nothing has happened". The temporary directory can be cleaned using an automated feature (i.e. clean on restart, clean everything that's over X hours/days old, etc.). Files should have a very short time span in this directory.

Next, rename the the image to its final place. File renames are atomic. They work or they do not.

If the system after this, the user row will be rolled back, but the file will be in its final destination. However, if after restart someone tries to add a new user that happens to have the same user id as the one that failed, their uploaded image will simply overwrite the existing one -- no harm, no foul. If the user id can not be re-used, you will have an orphaned image. But this can reasonably be cleaned up once a week or once a month through an automated routine.

Finally commit the transaction.

At this point everything is in the right place.

Comment: what if the last action - commit fails?

Comment: @StarCub Like I mentioned near the end. The user row will be rolled back, and the file will be in its final destination and be orphaned.

Answer (score 2):

you could do a class like this if you change your Image and User classes to the implied interface...

```
class Upload {

    public static function performUpload($name, $image, $ext) {

        $user = new User($name);
        $user->save();

        $img = new Image($image, $ext);
        $img->save();

        $isValid = $user->isValid() && $image->isValid();
        if (!$isValid) {

            $user->delete();
            $img->delete();
        }

        return $isValid;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this kind of approach, but how would you undo the saved image and saved user when one of the two is not valid or is valid but but writing to database or filesystem failed?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a perfect time to use try/catch block to control flow execution. It also appears that you are missing a big part of the puzzle, which is to save the image path created during the image save to the user, within the user table.

Following code is untested, but should put you on the right track:

```
Class User{

    static public function insert($name, $image, $ext)
    {
        $conn = DB_config::get();

        // This will force any PDO errors to throw an exception, so our following t/c block will work as expected
        // Note: This should be done in the DB_config::get method so all api calls to get will benefit from this attribute
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        try {

            $conn->beginTransaction();

            $sth = $conn->prepare("
                INSERT INTO users (name)
                values(:name);"
            );

            $sth->execute(array(":name" => $name));

            $imagePath = Image::saveImage($image, IMAGE_PATH . $conn->lastInsertId(). $ext));

            // Image path is an key component of saving a user, so if not saved lets throw an exception so we don't commit the transaction
            if (false === $imagePath) {
                throw new Exception(sprintf('Invalid $imagePath: %s', $imagePath));
            }

            $sth = $conn->prepare("UPDATE users SET image_path = :imagePath WHERE id = :userId LIMIT 1");

            $sth->bindValue(':imagePath', $imagePath, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindValue(':userId', $conn->lastInsertId(), PDO::PARAM_INT);

            $sth->execute();

            // If we made this far and no exception has been thrown, we can commit our transaction
            $conn->commit();

            return $conn->lastInsertId();

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            error_log(sprintf('Error saving user: %s', $e->getMessage()));

            $conn->rollback();
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think an update is necessary to save the imagepath. For example if the user is added and has ID "24" the image would be path/24.jpg.

Comment: sorry, it is necessary to store the path, in my application I store the extension instead.

Comment: @cooxie: I see. I added that update statement to give you an idea of how the try/catch will help with flow execution if you need to store the data required to link a user to an image within the database. Feel free to change it to satisfy your reqs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the [command pattern](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/let-your-players-undo-their-in-game-mistakes-with-the-command-pattern--gamedev-1391), and at first call the file operations, just after that the database operations. So you can use the transaction rollback by the database and write a manual rollback for file operations, for example you can store the content of the file in the memory or in a temporary storage for the case something fails... It is much easier to rollback files then rollback database records manually...

Ohh and lock resources always in the same order unless you want a deadlock... For example lock files always in ABC order and use the database always after file operations. Btw in rare cases you can use filesystem transactions. It depends on your server's filesystem...